# Powershell script to get computer info from domain

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm having some issues with my powershell script. When I run it, the SN (Serial Number) section doesn't get any information from the computer, however, when I run the command "`Get-WmiObject Win32_bios | fl SerialNumber`" on my computer it works.

```
# Get the list of all computer names and export to CSV file
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | select Name | 
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\computers.csv' -NoTypeInformation

# Import the computer names from CSV file and get the system information
$computers = Import-Csv “C:\Temp\computers.csv” | ForEach {

$computerSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
$computerOS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.Name
$computerCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $_.Name
$computerSN = Get-WmiObject Win32_bios | fl SerialNumber -ComputerName $_.Name

[PSCustomObject]@{
    'PCName' = $computerSystem.Name    
    'Model' = $computerSystem.Model   
    'RAM' = "{0:N2}" -f ($computerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB)    
    'CPU' = $computerCPU.Name    
    'OS' = $computerOS.caption   
    'SN' =$computerSN.SerialNumber
    'User' = $computerSystem.UserName    
}

} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\system-info.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Can someone please help me to resolve it?

Comment: `$computerSN = Get-WmiObject Win32_bios -ComputerName $_.Name`

Comment: I need to get the Serial Number only. should I change the 'SN' line so it only outputs the serial number? Get-WmiObject Win32_bios gives whole lot of info

Comment: I wrote a script a month or two back that gets a bunch of info from WMI/CIM and makes it pretty.  It's still missing the portscan function, but everything else in it is completed and done.  You may find some use in it, or at least in the code.

https://github.com/TheRealNoob/Scripts/blob/master/PowerShell/Get-SystemInfo.ps1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FL` or `Format-List` is for formatting the output. What you need is `Select-Object` or `Select` to filter output data.

```
$computerSN = Get-WmiObject Win32_bios -ComputerName $_.Name | Select-Object SerialNumber
```

Comment: Great! thank you very much. I can now see the Serial number in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_bios -ComputerName $_.Name | select SerialNumber
```

Use this instead of your current line.